# Stargazer regression table not displaying basic statistics

Tags: r, stargazer

I've created the following linear model adjusting for heteroskedasticity:

```
library(sandwich)
library(stargazer)

df <- data.frame(A = rnorm(1000, 500, 10), B = rnorm(1000, 500, 10), C = rnorm(1000, 500, 10), D = rnorm(1000, 500, 10))
mod <- lm(A ~ B + C + D, df)
vcov <- vcovHC(mod, type= "HC1")

# Creating robust standard-erros
robust_se <- sqrt(diag(vcov)) 
robust_se <- list(robust_se[1:3]) # Keeping the robust se for the intercept and variables B and C only, since I don't want to display D in the regression table

stargazer(mod, 
          summary = TRUE,
          keep = c("B", "C"),
          keep.stat = c("n", "f", "rsq", "adj.rsq"),
          notes.align = "l",
          dep.var.labels=c("Value"),
          covariate.labels=c("B", "C"),
          se = robust_se,
          out="directory.html")
```

I'm dealing with survey data, with the packeage "survey".

Even though I specify that I want to display R², adjusted R² and F Statistic, the printed regression table displays only the number of observations:

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: sex, out 01, 2021 - 20:58:05
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
\\[-1.8ex] & Value \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 B & 0.013 \\ 
  & (0.032) \\ 
  & \\ 
 C & $-$0.019 \\ 
  & (0.031) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Constant & 497.270$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (27.587) \\ 
  & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 1,000 \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know how to achieve this in `stargazer`. If you are interested in a more modern alternative (`stargazer` hasn’t been updated since 2018), you may want to try [the `modelsummary` package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) (disclaimer: I am the maintainer):

```r
df <- data.frame(A = rnorm(1000, 500, 10), B = rnorm(1000, 500, 10), C = rnorm(1000, 500, 10), D = rnorm(1000, 500, 10))
mod <- lm(A ~ B + C + D, df)

library(modelsummary)
modelsummary(mod, 
             vcov = "HC1", 
             output = "latex", 
             stars = TRUE)

# \begin{table}
# \centering
# \begin{tabular}[t]{lc}
# \toprule
#   & Model 1\\
# \midrule
# (Intercept) & \num{550.535}***\\
#  & (\num{26.979})\\
# B & \num{-0.018}\\
#  & \vphantom{1} (\num{0.030})\\
# C & \num{-0.075}*\\
#  & (\num{0.031})\\
# D & \num{-0.009}\\
#  & (\num{0.030})\\
# \midrule
# Num.Obs. & \num{1000}\\
# R2 & \num{0.007}\\
# R2 Adj. & \num{0.004}\\
# AIC & \num{7379.2}\\
# BIC & \num{7403.7}\\
# Log.Lik. & \num{-3684.604}\\
# F & \num{2.341}\\
# Std.Errors & HC1\\
# \bottomrule
# \multicolumn{2}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}+ p $<$ 0.1, * p $<$ 0.05, ** p $<$ 0.01, *** p $<$ 0.001}\\
# \end{tabular}
# \end{table}
```